# MSSQL Number from XML (varchar) cells

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing, shred

Can you tell me how to parse XML not only correctly, but beautifully, considering that the cell in nvarchar(max) is the number between two tags?

Example (XML):

```
<SignedLicenseInfo> <LicenseInfo> <ExpirationDate> 9223372036854775807 </ ExpirationDate> <AvailiableModules> 30 </ AvailiableModules> <PagesLimit> 708,976 </ PagesLimit> <PagesLimitRenewDate> 132274944000000000 </ PagesLimitRenewDate> <IsDefaultLicense> true </ IsDefaultLicense> <CustomModuleAuthorId> </ CustomModuleAuthorId> <IsCountRecognizedPagesOnly> false </ IsCountRecognizedPagesOnly> <IsCyrillicLanguageEnabled> true </ IsCyrillicLanguageEnabled> <MaximumNumberOfTemplateFields> 2147483647 </ MaximumNumberOfTemplateFields> <Type> 11 </ Type> <Amount> 0 </ Amount> </ StationInfo > </ LicenseStationInfo> <CustomFeatures> </ CustomFeatures> <LocalExpirationDate> 132271122849228006 </ LocalExpirationDate> </ LicenseInfo> <Signature> XXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXdfsd </ Signature> </ SignedLicenseInfo>
```

You need to get what is in  (708976). I got the following query in the database:

```
SELECT substring (s.Value, CHARINDEX ('<PagesLimit>', s.Value) +12, CHARINDEX ('</PagesLimit>', s.Value, CHARINDEX ('<PagesLimit>', s.Value) +12) - CHARINDEX ('<PagesLimit>', s.Value) -12) as My_String
from dbo.Settings s
```

How can it be made more concise and logical? And not by selecting the number of characters to and fro.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at XQUERY.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not well-formed... I had to remove some blanks and there are two closing tags, which are missing the opening tags (find them commented).

XML is not to be parsed as a *string with some fancy extras*. There are some native XML-methods using XQuery and XPath.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<SignedLicenseInfo>
  <LicenseInfo>
    <ExpirationDate> 9223372036854775807 </ExpirationDate>
    <AvailiableModules> 30 </AvailiableModules>
    <PagesLimit> 708,976 </PagesLimit>
    <PagesLimitRenewDate> 132274944000000000 </PagesLimitRenewDate>
    <IsDefaultLicense> true </IsDefaultLicense>
    <CustomModuleAuthorId />
    <IsCountRecognizedPagesOnly> false </IsCountRecognizedPagesOnly>
    <IsCyrillicLanguageEnabled> true </IsCyrillicLanguageEnabled>
    <MaximumNumberOfTemplateFields> 2147483647 </MaximumNumberOfTemplateFields>
    <Type> 11 </Type>
    <Amount> 0 </Amount>
    <!-- /StationInfo -->
    <!-- /LicenseStationInfo -->
    <CustomFeatures />
    <LocalExpirationDate> 132271122849228006 </LocalExpirationDate>
  </LicenseInfo>
  <Signature> XXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXdfsd </Signature>
</SignedLicenseInfo>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/SignedLicenseInfo/LicenseInfo/PagesLimit/text())[1]','varchar(max)');
```

This returns `708,976`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. Using the information provided, I did this:

```
declare @xml xml;
SELECT @xml = s.Value from dbo.Settings s where s.Name='LicenseString';
select @xml.value('(/SignedLicenseInfo/LicenseInfo/PagesLimit)[1]', 'int');
```